# How to update list-view data at run time in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have list-view with check-box which loads data from database. And i have a button too, when i press a button spinner is popping up with 2 messages "EDIT" and "DELETE". Delete is working perfectly fine. and if i select Edit option and press OK then Edit-Text is coming in alert window with two button Ok and Cancel.

Now i want that Whatever i enter in edit-text and press Ok button a list-view data which is selected (Checked) should update with new text whatever i have entered in edit-text. So how to achieve this. Please help me. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

My code for creating Database:

```
public class DataManipulatorClass {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabaseclass.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
static final String TABLE_NAME = "newtableclass";
private static Context context;
static SQLiteDatabase db;
OpenHelper openHelper = null;

private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;

private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME
        + "(classname) values (?)";

public DataManipulatorClass(Context context) {
    DataManipulatorClass.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(DataManipulatorClass.context);
    DataManipulatorClass.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    this.insertStmt = DataManipulatorClass.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
    //this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public long insert(String classname) {
    this.insertStmt.bindString(1, classname);
    return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
}

public void close() {
    if (openHelper != null) {
        openHelper.close();
    }
}

public void deleteAll() {
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}

public List<String[]> selectAll() {
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] { "id", "classname" }, null, null, null, null,
            "classname asc");
    int x = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String[] b1 = new String[] { cursor.getString(0),
                    cursor.getString(1) };
            list.add(b1);
            x = x + 1;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}

public boolean delete(long rowId) {
    /** this method deletes by id, the first column in your database */
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
                + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, classname TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

My Activity class:

```
public class Classes extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView imageViewNewClass, imageViewDelete;
ListView mListView;
String[] stg1;
List<String[]> names2 = null;
DataManipulatorClass dataManipulator;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSpinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

/** Sliding Menu */
boolean alreadyShowing = false;
private int windowWidth;
private Animation animationClasses;
private RelativeLayout classesSlider;
LayoutInflater layoutInflaterClasses;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.classes);

    imageViewNewClass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newclass);
    imageViewDelete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deletemenu);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.displaydata);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    windowWidth = display.getWidth();
    display.getHeight();
    layoutInflaterClasses = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    imageViewDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteMenuSpinner();
        }

        private void deleteMenuSpinner() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Classes.this);

            final Spinner spinnerDelete = new Spinner(Classes.this);
            alertDialog.setView(spinnerDelete);

            adapterSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Classes.this,
                    R.array.delete_menu,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapterSpinner
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerDelete.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                                    Delete operation code.....
                                }

                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        Classes.this);
                                final EditText updateClass = new EditText(
                                        Classes.this);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                                updateClass.setLayoutParams(lp);
                                alertDialogBuilder.setView(updateClass);
                                alertDialogBuilder
                                        .setTitle("Edit Operation");
                                alertDialogBuilder
                                        .setMessage("Enter New Class Name")
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton(
                                                "Yes",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(
                                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int id) {
                                                    }
                                                })
                                        .setNegativeButton(
                                                "No",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(
                                                            DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int id) {
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                });
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder
                                        .create();
                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.skirrmenu).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!alreadyShowing) {
                alreadyShowing = true;
                openSlidingMenu();
            }
        }
    });

    imageViewNewClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Classes.this, Class_Create.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Listview item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            SparseBooleanArray sp = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < sp.size(); i++) {
                if (sp.valueAt(i) == true) {
                    String s = ((TextView) mListView.getChildAt(i))
                            .getText().toString();
                    str = str.append(" " + s);
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(Classes.this,
                    "Selected items are " + str.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Intent intent = new Intent(Classes.this, PlayAudio.class);
            // startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    dataManipulator = new DataManipulatorClass(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    names2 = dataManipulator.selectAll();

    stg1 = new String[names2.size()];
    int x = 0;
    String stg;

    for (String[] name : names2) {
        stg = "Class Name : " + name[1];
        stg1[x] = stg;
        x++;
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.custom_list_item_multiple_choice, stg1);
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    mListView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.assignmentheader);
    mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    if (dataManipulator != null)
        dataManipulator.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() when OK button pressed. But it will update whole list. If this is what you need, then here is the solution.
To update one list item you can try this:

```
private void updateView(int index, String updateText){
    View v = yourListView.getChildAt(index - 
       yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    TextView someText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sometextview);
    someText.setText(updateText);
}
```

Comment: i think you are not getting my question. I want to update list-view data which i enter in edit-text not my whole list-view...

Comment: Where do i put this method, and what other changes are necessary to load edited data in list-view.

Comment: Put this method to your activity class, and call it in OK button listener. So you pass 2 parameters to method, index - get index of checked view, and updatetext - your new text.